# Sort array of active records by multiple columns

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given an array of active records

```
jobs = [#<Job _id: 1, created_at: 2014-07-15 19:18:40 UTC, organization: "Acme In.c">,
        #<Job _id: 3, created_at: 2014-05-20 09:27:38 UTC, organization: "Baxter">, 
        #<Job _id: 2, created_at: 2014-11-25 12:21:00 UTC, organization: "Wizard">, 
        #<Job _id: 3, created_at: 2015-01-15 07:20:10 UTC, organization: "Baxter">]
```

How can I sort the array first by `organization` in ascending order A->Z and then by `created_at` descending to end up with this ...

```
jobs = [#<Job _id: 1, created_at: 2014-07-15 19:18:40 UTC, organization: "Acme In.c">,
        #<Job _id: 3, created_at: 2015-01-15 07:20:10 UTC, organization: "Baxter">,
        #<Job _id: 3, created_at: 2014-05-20 09:27:38 UTC, organization: "Baxter">,
        #<Job _id: 2, created_at: 2014-11-25 12:21:00 UTC, organization: "Wizard">]
```

I've tried to to do `jobs.sort_by{|j| [j.organization, j.created_at]}` but I'm not really sure how to specify multiple asc/desc rules and the closest I've gotten is sorted by organization but then sorting by created gives me oldest to newest instead of newest to oldest. I've also tried to group first and then sort but I couldn't get it to work either. Any help if appreciated.

Comment: How about changing the `sort_by` array to `[j.organization, -sec]`, where `sec` is "seconds since epoch" obtained from `j.created_at`?

Comment: Any particular reason that you're not sorting them inside the database?

Comment: I am aggregating multiple calls from different parts of my code and inserting them into the array so I would much rather prefer just handling the sorting once I have all the jobs into the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way is to use [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) and [`<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) and [`nonzero?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F) like this:

```
jobs.sort{|a,b| 
  (a.organization <=> b.organization).nonzero? ||
  (b.created_at <=> a.created_at)
}
```

This code says:

1. Compare A and B by organization.
2. If they differ, then we have our answer.
3. If they are the same, then we need to do more.
4. Compare B and A by time. (Note B & A are in reverse order)
5. If they differ, then we have our answer.
6. If they are the same, then the sort order doesn't matter. (Ruby sort is "unstable")

Example code independent of ActiveRecord:

```
require 'time'
require 'ostruct'

jobs = [
  OpenStruct.new(_id: 1, created_at: Time.parse("2014-07-15 19:18:40 UTC"), organization: "Acme Inc"),
  OpenStruct.new(_id: 3, created_at: Time.parse("2014-05-20 09:27:38 UTC"), organization: "Baxter"), 
  OpenStruct.new(_id: 2, created_at: Time.parse("2014-11-25 12:21:00 UTC"), organization: "Wizard"), 
  OpenStruct.new(_id: 3, created_at: Time.parse("2015-01-15 07:20:10 UTC"), organization: "Baxter")
]
```

Comment: Suppose `a.organization <=> b.organization`, so you want `-1` returned to `sort`, but `true` will be returned. Don't you need `(a.organization != b.organization) ?  a.organization <=> b.organization : b.created_at <=> a.created_at`?

Comment: True is never returned from any of the operators in that code. If a.org == b.org, then a.org <=> b.org is 0. Which means (0).nonzero? is nil, so the second clause is evaluated. I'll add example code so you can try it and see.

Comment: I'm almost there with this answer except it sometimes doesn't arrange quite right. If I have `"AB Transport"`, `"DBC"`, and `"Paul's"` as organizations it returns:
`AB Transport 07/30/2014`, `Paul's 07/22/2014`, `Paul's 07/22/2014`, `DBC 07/30/2014`, `Paul's 07/21/2014` ..... I simplified the returns to save  all the typing.

Comment: I take that back it seems that my db was out of wack with some faulty records and it works fine now. Thanks for your solution !!

Comment: Arrgggh! I thought all methods ending with a question mark returned `true`or `false`. But wait! [Numeric#nonzero?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F) returns `self` or `nil`! Yes, it is more useful with those return values, but I don't like that naming one bit. I had a quick look through `Numeric`, `Fixed`, `Float`, `String`, `Array`, `Hash` and `Enumerable`.  There are plenty of  `?` methods in those classes. How many of those return something other than `true` or `false`? Just two: `Numeric#nonzero?` and `Float#infinite?` (but not `Float#finite?`)!

Comment: @Cary Haha! Yes that whole chunk of code is bonkers for several reasons. Ideally Ruby will someday add the `<->` comparison operator, which returns  -1, false, 1.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Try `jobs.order("organization ASC", "created_at DESC")` or the following

```
jobs.order("organization ASC").order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: I'm getting the records from multiple places in my code and just insert them into the array so I would like to just sort everything once I have all the jobs in the array.